# How to remove outline appeared on click in Bootstrap UI Accordion

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use angular-ui bootstrap accordion to hold bootstrap table inside the heading.
When user clicks on the accordion heading and it opens, a strange outline appears. It looks like this (the light blue rectangle around "Some title"):
[image]

I understand it happens because I used the `<div>` , but how can I eliminate this behavior?

The code is:

```
<accordion close-others="true">
  <accordion-group>
    <accordion-heading>
      <div>Some title</div>
    </accordion-heading>
    Text
  </accordion-group>
  <accordion-group>
    <accordion-heading>
      <div>Another title</div>
    </accordion-heading>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Comment: A fiddle'd be helpful.

Comment: That blue line is your user focus. Its not something that you really want to remove. you can target it with :focus

Answer (score 18):

The outline is added to the `panel-heading panel-title <a> tag`, which has an `.accordion-toggle` class. So, to avoid the `*` catch-all selector you can do this:

```
.accordion-toggle:focus{outline: none;}
```

With this solution there is no need for !important either ([so you'll respect the devs who come after you](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)).

---

`outline` is a shorthand property whose only required value is `outline-style`.  In this case I am setting `outline-style` to `none`.

---

[This is a great article](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) that explains specificity, if you're not convinced that !important should be avoided in all but a couple of cases.

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

`accordion * {outline: 0 !important;}`

Modifying [etaiso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237114/how-to-remove-outline-appeared-on-click-in-bootstrap-ui-accordion#comment48576833_30237206) comment

Answer (score 2):

try to add a class inside the title div like:

```
<div class="title-div">
```

then on css, try with:

```
.title-div:focus {outline: 0 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.accordion-heading:focus{outline:0;border:none;}
```

Comment: It didnt work.. I found that `html * {outline: 0 !important;}` did the work, but there must be more elegant way. need to find the exact css selectors for this.

Comment: That's what I said, but I don't think it's a bad practice as it overrides all classes

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it worked for me**

```
.ng-scope .accordion-toggle  { outline: 0 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.accordion-toggle:hover, .accordion-toggle:focus, .accordion-toggle:active{

    text-decoration: none;
    outline-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for your example?

Answer (score 0):

100% work will be :

```css
a:focus, a:hover {
  color: #23527c;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```